# What do we call the state of being proper?

Tags: terminology

The set $\{1, 2\}$ is a proper subset of $\{1, 2, 3\}$. But $\{1, 2, 3\}$ itself is not.

More generally, we might want to define a notion of "proper-ness" that derives from this basic notion of proper super- and subsets. For example, I might want to talk about a sequence $(f_i)_{i = 1}^n$ of surjective functions, and call it "proper" if not one of the $f_i$s is a bijection. Then I might have some way of manipulating such sequences, and I might want to write that "... is not in general preserved under [such a manipulation]", where ... is the name of the state of being proper.

What do we call the property of being proper? Do we call it "propriety", perhaps, or something else?

Comment: I don't think there is a general concept of proper-ness. Propriety has a social meaning that seems odd to my ears, and I've never heard it used in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paper "[Completeness and properness of refinement operators in inductive logic programming](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0743106697000770)" uses *properness*, though the authors may not be English first-language speakers.

Wiktionary also has this meaning as the third offered for *[properness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/properness)*

*-ness* and *-less* are productive in English (for example as in *memorylessness*) so I see nothing wrong with *properness*.